# Certificate error while running JUnit in Spring Java application in IntelliJ

Tags: java, junit, certificate, intellij-14

I am getting this error while running JUnits in Spring Java Project IntelliJ for some of the JUnits only, which is making real connection with external system with URL

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate your problem and add some details? How do you build the external connections? (code) Assuming you want to establish encrypted communication: Do your external endpoints use certificates signed by an established authority? Are you using some kind of firewall software that inspects https connections?

Answer (score 0):

I installed zscaler certificate in jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts keystore and updated cacerts under directory java\test\resources\certs location. It resolved the issue.